# How do I assemble a <ul> using jQuery append()?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the append function and encountered this:

```
$("#details").append('<ul>');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#details").append('<li>something</li>');
}
$("#details").append('</ul>');
```

It appears that the `<li>` elements renders OUTSIDE the `<ul>` tag.

Is this a jQuery bug?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

No, it's a programmer bug.  `<li>`s are attached to their `<ul>` or `<ol>`, not to its container.  And appending a close tag is nonsensical.

You're basically working as if what you were appending were raw HTML, and it's not; you're actually working with the DOM.

Try this:

```
var list = $("#details").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    list.append('<li>something</li>');
```

**Note:** please see (and upvote) Blixt's answer, which expands on a couple different options that are superior for various purposes.  It deserves attention and hasn't been getting it.

Comment: Ah, should have known this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That will return the `#details` element and put it in `list`. Then the `<li>` elements will be added to the `#details` element. You need to select the `<ul>` element after creating it.

Comment: Thanks, Blixt.  I was trying to research whether `append()` returned the parent or child and wasn't having any luck.

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation See my answer though, I changed it to be more concise and correct (because `#details` can theoretically contain several `<ul>` elements.)

Comment: It is better to put all li's into a string or better an array and append only once at the end. Especially if you have long lists.

Comment: Closing </li> tags are, indeed, sensical.  They're required for XHTML validation.

Comment: Yes, the closing `<li>` tags are fine and appropriate and you'll note I included them.  I meant the `append()` of a lone `</ul>` in OP's code sample.

Comment: He meant the `.append('</ul>')` operation. In the DOM, you don't have an object for closing tags; a single DOM object represents the whole tag and its contents.

Answer (score 94):

Nope, you can't use it like that. `append` is an atomic operation, which creates the element directly.

```
// The <ul> element is added to #details, then it is selected and the jQuery
// selection is put in the "list" variable.
var list = $('<ul/>').appendTo('#details');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // New <li> elements are created here and added to the <ul> element.
    list.append('<li>something</li>');
}
```

Alternatively, generate the HTML and add it all at once (this will be more similar to your original code):

```
var html = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html += '<li>something</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';
$('#details').append(html);
```

This code is noticeably faster when dealing with many elements.

If you need a reference to the list, just do the following instead of `$('#details').append(html);`:

```
var list = $(html).appendTo('#details');
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the closing </UL> is not needed when doing `append`? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Sabuncu In the first example, the DOM nodes are being created programmatically so the first call (`$('<ul/>')`) already created the `<ul>` node, then the `<li>` nodes are added to it.

The closing `</ul>` tag is only used for parsing HTML (turning it into a DOM node tree) and tells the parser when to move one step up the tree (out of the `<ul>` node).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I understand; in DOM, there are no opening/closing tags, as objects are already defined to have a type, such as a UL. Some examples I have seen elsewhere use `<ul{SPACE}/>` (I added the {SPACE} for emphasis) but I guess the space is optional?

Comment: @Sabuncu Correct, in HTML (which is structured text [or "markup", or "code"]) you need to open and close tags, and as you described, `<ul />` is a shorthand for `<ul></ul>`. In DOM, you're working with objects that are the result of HTML, so it's a structure, not text or code. More specifically, it's a tree structure, just like folders and files on a disk, where one DOM node can contain many others (like a directory). Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score 8):

I think there's a problem in your loop

```
for (var i = - i < 10; i++)
    $("#details").append('<li>something</li>');
```

should be I think

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    $("#details ul").append('<li>something</li>');
```

and lose the following from the end

```
$("#details").append('</ul>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/awucu)**

**EDIT:**

Based on George IV's comment, in order to avoid appending `<li>` elements to any `<ul>` that may be a child of the element with id "**details**", simply give the `<ul>` element an id when you append it-

```
$("#details").append('<ul id="appended">');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    $("#appended").append('<li>something</li>');
```

you may also find this article interesting - [43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

Comment: whoa there! bad selector: "#details ul". what if there is more than one unordered list that is a child of #details?

Comment: give it an id when you append it and then use the id. I've based the answer on what is given in the question and made no assumptions about the rest of the OP's markup

Answer (score 1):

For a small static list, I prefer to unroll into a single expression.

```
$('#details')
   .append($('<ul/>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
      .append('<li>something</li>')
   );
```

Comment: That won't work though, because you'll be appending the `<li>` elements to the `#details` element. You could do it like this: `$('<ul/>').appendTo('#details').append('<li>something</li>').append(...`

Comment: You're right, I see now. I find it a bit confusing, but that's just my opinion of course.

Comment: It's just my style.  The indents make it clear to me.  All others can resort to, IMHO, less readable loop constructs.  I ♥ Functional Programming

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like if you have  the data in an Array.

var appendToUl = array.join("

+ array+

");

It is much faster