# Dynamically create and append ul after existing ul in div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu and I need to dynamically add another ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right with one li. Here is my actual HTML:

```
<div id="menu navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="level1 static nav navbar-nav">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and after that ul I need to append another ul via jQuery (this is result what I need after run script)

```
<div id="menu navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="level1 static nav navbar-nav">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
  **<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="/Profile.aspx" class="img-nav-link">Profil</a>
    </li>
  </ul>**
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your existing script.

Comment: Have you tried jquery append? Try googling that. You could even do innerHTML!

Comment: As easy as search "Append an element with Jquery"

Comment: Use [$('#menu').append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append to an existing div

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1126055/588079 (I don't consider it an exact duplicate however).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#menu').append($('<ul/>').addClass('nav navbar-nav navbar-right'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery append, or you could use Javascript .innerHTML! Like this:

```
$("menu navbar").append('<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="/Profile.aspx" class="img-nav-link">Profil</a></li></ul>');
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('whatever').innerHTML += 'whatever';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe spaces are allowed in ID attribute. But if they are it would be something like this:

```
$("#menu navbar").append('<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="/Profile.aspx" class="img-nav-link">Profil</a></li></ul>')
```

Also, more complicated:

```
var ul = $("<ul/>",{
  class : "nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
}),
li = $("<li/>"),
a = $("<a/>",{
  href: "/Profile.aspx",
  class: "img-nav-link",
  text: "Profil"
});
a.appendTo(li)
li.appendTo(ul);
ul.appendTo("#menu navbar")
```

But you probably must change the ID from `menu navbar` to `menuNavbar` or something.

Comment: Your struggle is right. ID must be one word. With that space it looks like there are two IDs :)