# How to append ul li in body

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a `ul` with an id `thumbsList` and `li's.`
I am writing this code.

```
   $(body).append('ul.#thumbsList');
```

But this dosent work..
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I assemble a <ul> using jQuery append()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126055/how-do-i-assemble-a-ul-using-jquery-append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(body).append('<ul id="thumbsList"><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul>');
```

Comment: This answer has syntax error and still OP has accepted this answer out of other correct answers. `AWESOME.`

Comment: OP has got the way how to solve his problem. He is smart enough to correct syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("body").append('<ul id="thumbsList"><li></li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9dovx193/)

```
//i = number of li you want

$('body').append($('<ul></ul>').attr('id','thumbsList')).append(function(e){
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
        $(this).append('<li/>')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the entire string written out as such:

```
$("body").append("<ul id='thumbslist'></ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").append("<ul id='thumbsList'></ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, [JQUERY APPEND](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) and also check [DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/w0L49z95/)

```
var add_thumblist   =   '<ul id="thumbsList"><li>List item 1</li><li>List item 2</li><li>List item 3</li></ul>';
$("body").append(add_thumblist);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'ul.#thumbsList'` this element is not yet created.

Do this

```
var $ul=$('<ul>',{'id':'thumbsList'});
$(body).append($ul)
```

Comment: And if you element is already there you may want to do this

`$(body).append($('ul.#thumbsList'));`

Bcause it takes jquery element and not selector.